# Rebasing someone's branch for them

Tags: git

If someone is having difficulty rebasing their branch (such as it's really far off from where master is because they've been lazy about keeping up). Is it safe to check out their remote branch, rebase it for them (doing all of the manual updates by hand yourself) and the push it over on top of their remote branch?

Comment: Define "safe"?  Given you have the right permissions, you could do it.  They would have to sort things out on their end after fetch though.  If that's their only branch, should be easy, if they have branches off of that branch, it'll be a little more work.

Comment: In Git, branches are so cheap that you can checkout, rebase and push to their *other* remote branch. It's my preferred workflow in case of big and uncertain changes -- first create a clean branch off the original branch, and do the rebase or other heavy and potentially dangerous operation in the copied branch. After making sure all's fine, you can delete the original branch. You can undo a rebase using reflog, but it should be considered a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to check out their remote branch, rebase it for them (doing all of the manual updates by hand yourself) and the push it over on top of their remote branch?

Yes and no: you would have to *force* the push, ie to publish a different history for their branch.
So you would need to communicate that they have to *reset* their local branch to the new `origin/abranch`, and keep on working from there.

```
git checkout abranch
git branch abranch_old # keep a pointer to the old history just in case
git reset --hard origin/abranch
```